# Resource Not Found error while creating a custom master page for Sharepoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

Resource Not Found (Master Page is not found) error is shown when a custom master page is created for SharePoint Hosted App according to steps given in given link: [Master Page for Sharepoint Hosted App](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/817340/Creating-Custom-Master-Page-for-Hosted-Apps)